# Select Parent and Child in SQL Server with HierarchyID

Tags: sql-server

I have table with HierarchyID and wanna to select parent and child base on child attribute.

Here's the table :

```
CREATE TABLE #BOMTbl
(
  ItemNo   HIERARCHYID NOT NULL,
  Lvl AS ItemNo.GetLevel() PERSISTED,
  MatID VARCHAR(25) NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_#BOMTbl PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED(ItemNo)
);

insert into #BOMTbl (ItemNo,MatID) values
('/1/',''),
('/1/1/',''),
('/1/1/1/','MA-A'),
('/1/1/2/','MA-A'),
('/1/1/3/','MA-B'),
('/1/2/',''),
('/1/2/1/','MA-B'),
('/1/2/2/','MA-B'),
('/1/3/',''),
('/1/3/1/','PW-A'),
('/1/3/2/','PW-A'),
('/1/4/',''),
('/1/4/1/','PW-B'),
('/1/4/2/','PW-B'),
('/1/5/','0001'),
('/1/6/','0001'),
('/1/7/','0002'),
('/1/8/','0003')
```

I want to select the table with the result like this :

```
ItemNo  ItemID  Lvl MatID
0x5AC0  /1/1/   2   
0x5AD6  /1/1/1/ 3   MA-A
0x5ADA  /1/1/2/ 3   MA-A
0x5B40  /1/2/   2   
0x5ADE  /1/1/3/ 3   MA-B
0x5B56  /1/2/1/ 3   MA-B
0x5B5A  /1/2/2/ 3   MA-B
```

Comment: Is that result comes from all the children with MatId like 'MA%'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select ItemNo, ItemNo.ToString() AS ItemID, Lvl, MatID from BOMTbl p
WHERE exists
(select * from BOMTbl c
 where c.MatID like 'MA%'
 and (c.ItemNo.GetAncestor(1) = p.ItemNo 
      or c.ItemNo.GetAncestor(0) = p.ItemNo ) )
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/825d3/8)</kbd>

Comment: Hi Chang, Thanks for the code. It's the simple one :). Can you suggest me the book or article about HierarchyID query.

Comment: @user3335691 Search "HierarchyID" in SO. Test those cases with sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with:

```
with cte as (
    select *
    from #BOMTbl
    where MatId like 'MA%'
)
select *
from cte as child
union
select parent.* 
from cte as child
join #BOMTbl as parent
    on child.ItemNo.GetAncestor(1) = parent.ItemNo
```

Comment: I think use left join instead of union should be more efficient.

Comment: In what way? Specifically, what *specific* query using a left join would you suggest that will be "more efficient" than what I've got here? I'm not being defensive, but you can't say that left joins are always more efficient than a union. All you can do is say that a specific query will be more efficient than another specific query given the circumstances of the data (structure, quality, and quantity).

Comment: Sorry! Only in this case I mean, `select distinct parent.*
from  BOMTbl as parent
left join cte as child
    on child.ItemNo.GetAncestor(1) = parent.ItemNo
        or child.ItemNo.GetAncestor(0) = parent.ItemNo 
where child.itemno is not null` will come to the same result by decreaseing one table scan.

Comment: Now that's a suggestion I can get behind; +1! :)

Answer (score 0):

Will following query help?

```
select ItemNo, ItemNo.ToString() AS ItemID, Lvl, MatID from #BOMTbl
WHERE ItemNo.IsDescendantOf('/1/1/') = 1
UNION
select ItemNo, ItemNo.ToString() AS ItemID, Lvl, MatID from #BOMTbl
WHERE ItemNo.IsDescendantOf('/1/2/') = 1
```

Comment: @zhoingxiao37 : Thanks for your reply. I follow your code for union two query and the result is correct :). :

select itemno, itemno.ToString() as ItemID, Lvl, MatID 
from #BOMTbl 
where MatID LIKE 'MA%'
union
Select ItemNo , ItemNo.ToString() as ItemID,Lvl, MatID 
from #BOMTbl
where ItemNo  in (
           Select ItemNo .GetAncestor(ItemNo .GetLevel()-(select max (lvl-1) from #BOMTbl where MatID LIKE 'MA%')).ToString()
           from #BOMTbl 
           where MatID LIKE 'MA%'
           )